# Sketching the global phase portrait for a version of the Lotka-Volterra system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to sketch the phase portrait for a version of Lotka-Volterra given by $$\begin{cases} \dot{x} = x(3-x-2y)\\ \dot{y} = y(2-x-y) \end{cases}.$$

I can sketch this just fine except for the brown curve (shown below).

- The fixed points are: $(0,0), (0,2), (3,0), (1,1)$.
- The linearised system is given by $Df(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}
  3-2x-2x & -2x \\ 
  -y & 2-x-2y
  \end{pmatrix}$.

So we have:

1. $Df(0,0) = \begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$, $\lambda_1 = 3, \lambda_2 = 2, e_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$
2. $Df(0,2) = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 2 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$, $\lambda_1 = -1, \lambda_2 = -2, e_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}, e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$
3. $Df(3,0) = \begin{pmatrix}3 & -6 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$, $\lambda_1 = -3, \lambda_2 = -1, e_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$
4. $Df(1,1) = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & -2 \\ -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$, $\lambda_1 = -1 + \sqrt{2}, \lambda_2 = -1-\sqrt{2}, e_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}, e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}$

So respectively we have an unstable node, a stable node, a stable node and a saddle point.

I'm having difficulty sketching the stable manifold for the saddle point. I know that the manifold must contain $(1,1)$ and is tangent to $(1,1) + E^s$, where $E^s$ is the space spanned by the eigenvector $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{pmatrix}$, i.e. the manifold must be tangent to the line $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x-1)+1$.

Here is a sketch of the phase portrait by the lecturer:

[image]

Since the manifold needs to be tangent to $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x-1)+1$, why is the brown curve not concave downward then concave upward (rather than the way it's drawn, i.e. concave upward then concave downward)?

Comment: The separatrix is indeed concave downward from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$. It is tangent to the $y$-axis at $(0,0)$ hence it could not be concave upwards on the whole curve from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$. To see this, note that every solution in the positive quadrant near $(0,0)$ is such that $y^3\approx x^2$. The separatrix happens to be concave downwards after $(1,1)$ as well but there is no clear argument why it should.

Comment: @Did Thanks for the confirmation. I've been told that the tangency condition doesn't actually tell us anything about the curvature (which I guess why you said that there is no clear argument), but we can in fact compute the manifold itself using a trick from earlier in the module involving a power series. The point here is to get an approximate idea of how the global phase portrait looks like, so I guess that's why we didn't do it.